# How to insert new element to existing array in usermeta?

Tags: user-meta, array

How to insert new element to existing array in usermeta? This code doesn't work because it makes nested array.

```
$data = array(
get_user_meta(2, 'fruits', false),
  'apple',
  'pear',
  'peach'
);
update_user_meta(2, 'fruits', $data , false);
$sud = get_user_meta(2, 'fruits', false);

echo print_r($sud);
```

Comment: $data = array_merge( get_user_data(...), ['apple,'pear',...] );

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's analyze your code and what it does.

Assuming that the current fruits stored in the database are 'pineapple' and 'orange', `get_user_meta(2, 'fruits', false)` will return something like this:

```
array( array( 'pineapple', 'orange' ) )
```

This is because you passed `false` as the third argument, `$single`. The function returns an array if `$single` is `false` and the value of the meta data field if `$single` is `true` ([docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/)). That is because there could be multiple `fruits` entries in the database, so WordPress would return all of them if not explicitly told not to.

Since you only have one meta key storing all your fruits, we don't want a list of all entries. Setting `$single` to `true` will result in this:

```
array( 'pineapple', 'orange' )
```

Let's combine this with your `$data` array:

```
$data = array(
  get_user_meta(2, 'fruits', false),
  'apple',
  'pear',
  'peach'
);

// results in: array( array( array( 'pineapple', 'orange' ) ), 'apple', 'pear', peach' )

$data = array(
  get_user_meta(2, 'fruits', true),
  'apple',
  'pear',
  'peach'
);

// results in: array( array( 'pineapple', 'orange' ), 'apple', 'pear', peach' )
```

Still not ideal! What you want is one single array containing all fruits. That means you need to *merge* these arrays:

```
$data = array_merge(
  get_user_meta(2, 'fruits', true),
  array(
    'apple',
    'pear',
    'peach'
  )
);

// results in: array( 'pineapple', 'orange', 'apple', 'pear', peach' )
```

Now, we can finally update the user meta accordingly:

```
update_user_meta(2, 'fruits', $data , false);
```

Here's another `false` at the fourth position. What does it mean? It's the `$prev_value` argument. If specified, the function only updates existing metadata entries with the specified value. Otherwise, it updates all entries ([docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_metadata/)). Passing `false` is the same as not specifying anything.

But what if we passed `$prev_value`? Let's have a look!

```
update_user_meta( 2, 'fruits', $data , array( 'pineapple', 'orange' ) );
// does update, because that's what's in the database.

update_user_meta( 2, 'fruits', $data );
// does update as well

update_user_meta( 2, 'fruits', $data , array( 'cherry', 'banana' ) );
// does not update, because that's not what is in the database.
```

In your case, I'd simply use `update_user_meta( 2, 'fruits', $data );` because WordPress automatically turns it into the third example.

Let's get our updated data from the database again! Remember, you don't want an array of entries, so we use `get_user_meta( 2, 'fruits', true )`

```
get_user_meta(2, 'fruits', false);

// results in array( 'pineapple', 'orange', 'apple', 'pear', peach' )
```

That's it!

Comment: you are a great tutor. loved the way you explained array_merge and prev_value in easy and simple words. learning value!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$data = get_user_meta(2, 'fruits', false);
array_push($data, 'apple', 'pear', 'peach');
update_user_meta(2, 'fruits', $data , false);
$sud = get_user_meta(2, 'fruits', false);

echo print_r($sud);
```

Comment: This script does same thing as mine.

Comment: Is it possible to insert data or I need other solution?

Comment: I think most of the solutions will do pretty much the same as this one with some minor structural changes. Because that's what update_user_meta function does. Here is the [doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta). You can check it here.